# Got errors when I do yarn build (it calls tsc) and no errors when I do tsc in the terminal?

Tags: typescript, compilation, hadoop-yarn, tsc

Any idea why I get errors when I do `yarn build` (it calls `tsc`) and no errors when I do `tsc` in the terminal?

In package.json, I have

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
  }
```

`tsc` in the terminal throw no errors:

[image]

`yarn build` in the terminal throw errors:
[image]

In tsconfig.json I `skipLibCheck = true` so I ignore the folder `node_module`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
```

Full video here: https://app.usebubbles.com/c1d689be-bbf4-46c9-bd89-5983351d6717

Comment: `tsc` in terminal would use your global typescript binary and `yarn build` would call your locally scoped typescript installation; perhaps the versions differ?

Comment: Yep! You got it! Thanks